# First few words ignored while writing to xilinx coregen FIFO

Tags: xilinx, fifo, hdl

I am using xilinx coregen FIFO. I am writing some data (its nothing but some counter values) but I feel it is skipping first two words. I have no idea about this behavior. All the signals are generated using simple combination logic as a part of testbench.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

[image: In this image data written is starting with 4. But its seen that output data is starting with 12]

Comment: Can you rename your signals to understandable signals and sort them into groups (read interface, write interface) -> right-click add to group. Your VHDL or Verilog code could also help to solve the question.

Comment: Does your simulation shows the full output from the FIFO?

Comment: Don't you need to wait a few (i think it was something around 3-5) clock cycles after the release of the reset?